# Plotting software with functionality for creating uncertainty shaded

Tags: graphs, data-analysis

I’m in the process of completing some data analysis and am looking for a (free) graphing software that has the functionality to create scientific plots that have a smooth error region about my fitting function that is shaded by some percentage or specified amount. The reason for this is that I have two independent sources of error that I wish to compare in an overlayed fashion - the error bars will already be used and I want the plot to be clear in this regard.

Ideally I’d like something with a GUI, but I’ll understand if that’s not feasible. Alternatively, if there’s a way to do this with MatLab, Mathematica, Gnuplot, etc., and I simply missed it, I can follow up there. I’m not an *expert* in these things, so I thought I might ask here.